# Rails 3 - Nested attributes and inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, inheritance, nested-attributes

Hy,

I have a problem in a nested form. Actually, I have two problems, but the second one is minor.
The basic structure is like this :

```
class Connectable
  has_one :web_account
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :web_account
end

class Person < Connectable
end

class WebAccount
   belongs_to :owner, class_name => `Connectable`
end
```

And now, I would like to create a nested form to create a Person and a WebAccount at the same time. I have the following code :

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %> 
   ...
   <%= f.fields_for web_accounts do |child| %>
      ....
   <end>
<end>
```

The only important attribute for WebAccount is name and is a string.

Note also the plural used in defining the child_form. I don't know why, but when I use a singular (which seems right to me), rails just prints out an empty form, while using a plural works just fine. I added some code in the controller to remplace the :web_accounts hash entry given by the form with :web_account.

More importantly, I get following error :

```
WebAccount(#97097470) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#83887850)
```

I also tried doing it in a console, defining following hash :

```
p = { :name => "ab", :lastname => "cd", :web_account => { :name => "ab.cd" }}
```

but with the same result.

Here is the code in my controller :

```
def create
  params[:person][:status] = Status.where(:name => params[:person][:status]).first

  # Transforms the web_accounts entry into web_account
  params[:person][:web_account] = params[:person][:web_accounts]
  params[:person].delete(:web_accounts)

  @person = Person.new(params[:person])

  .... (the rest is the standard response)

end
```

The error is given at line 58, which is the Person.new(...) line in the code above. I could print out the full framework trace if needed, but it is, as usual, rather long.

Why isn't this working? I just can't my head around it, as it seems to me that I have followed all the online tutorials... Could it the be the inheritance?

Comment: Please include the code in your create/update action.  It would also be helpful to indicate what line in your controller is giving the exception.

Comment: Here you go, I edited the question. Thank you for the quick response, btw :D !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `web_account_attributes` instead of `web_account`. [Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Try in the console:

```
p = { :name => "ab", :lastname => "cd", :web_account_attributes => { :name => "ab.cd" }}
```

Comment: Hmm.. could you copy-paste console output here?

Comment: Thank you ! It worked in console and I changed the code that modified the params hash to rename it to :web_account_attributes. It works now, in console and with the form. I still don't exactly get why the "standard" method that one can encounter on the web didn't work. But thank you very much anyway !

Comment: `web_account=` accessor is one of the bunch methods generated by `has_one` method. It assumes that you will pass an AR model to it.